# Access relative CSS/JS files with htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was recently asked if I could make my friends server address more user friendly. His current urls looks like this:

```
http://wwww.example.com/site/index.php?page=home
http://wwww.example.com/site/index.php?page=about/john
http://wwww.example.com/site/index.php?page=portfolio/concept-art/2013
```

He would like them to look like this

```
http://wwww.example.com/site/home
http://wwww.example.com/site/about/john
http://wwww.example.com/site/portfolio/concept-art/2013
```

which I thought would be pretty simple so I wrote this following rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js)/
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

which seems to work for the basic links like

```
http://wwww.example.com/site/home
```

but for something like this

```
http://wwww.example.com/site/about/john
```

none of the css or js will load. So I fixed that for now by making all of the files absolute paths but I am worried that my friend is going to add a new plugin or something and forget that he has to make it an absolute path.

***My Question***

Is there something I could change or add in my htaccess file to get the css and js files to load with a relative path? If so what would I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better to use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then for css/js/images better to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Alternatively** You can try adding this in your page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

OR

```
<base href="http://domain.com/site/" />
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't even think of `base` always forget the basic HTML solutions. haha. I added a php function to auto generate the base in case he ever moves his site, but other than that this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there something I could change or add in my htaccess file to get the css and js files to load with a relative path? If so what would I need to do?

You could just add the proper relative URI base in your page header:

```
<base href="/site/" />
```

Or you could brute force redirect them using mod_rewrite (not preferable):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [L]
```

Comment: I always forget to try the basic html solutions like `base`. haha.